# Uva 10252, cannot figure out

Tags: algorithm

I have tried all the test cases, but online judge still shows me its a wrong answer

https://onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=1193

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int min(int a, int b){
    return a>b?b:a;
}
int main(void) {
  int i,j,s1[26],s2[26];
  char str1[1005],str2[1005];
  while(fgets(str1,1000,stdin)&&fgets(str2,1000,stdin)){
    if(strlen(str1)==0&&strlen(str2)==0) break; 
    memset(s1,0,sizeof(s1));
    memset(s2,0,sizeof(s2));
    for(i=0;i<strlen(str1);i++) s1[str1[i]-'a']++;
    for(i=0;i<strlen(str2);i++) s2[str2[i]-'a']++;
    for(i=0;i<26;i++){
        for(j=0;j<min(s1[i],s2[i]);j++){
            putchar('a'+i);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide more information about what you are trying and what exactly is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Read carefully `man fgets`:

> The newline, if any, is retained.

Your `i < strlen(str*)` loops convert one too many character. And subtracting `'a'` from a newline doesn't do any good.

Comment: I use fgets because there are some empty cases, such us:
str1="", str2="pretty", how can I get them without fgets at the same time, and exit when both of them are empty?

Comment: It is OK (and right) to use `fgets`. Just don't iterate over the newline (it shall be a last character of the string).

Comment: I can get the answer by using fgets
while(1){ fgets() fgets()), but how can I end the program, the program Time limit exceeded